# HELP! Deleted partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, testdisk, undelete

I have a laptop with a 500GB HDD I have 3 partitions (40GB Windows 7, 150GB Ubuntu and 280GB for storage in windows) but I wanted to resize the 40GB partitions because after installing some programs I run low on space...While I was in win7 I tried to resize the 40GB partition...but when I deleted the 280GB volume the ubuntu volume was also deleted!(I don't know why this happend...) I had put all files from 280GB partition into the ubuntu partition as a backup...but now I lost them! Currently I cannot boot in win7 either because when I start the laptop pops up the grub rescue...I have live boot on ubuntu from usb...I have done nothing since I realized what I did just turned off the laptop and boot into ubuntu via usb. I know I can use test disk to take the data back but I have no space to put them! and I am afraid that if I install ubuntu again the data will be lost...

In few words I want somehow to "undelete" the action I did which was to delete the partition

Comment: Good luck, because I believe you will need some. I would search for partition undelete programs, that can run from an usb bootable disk. Something like that https://www.google.com/?q=undelete+partition+usb+boot#safe=active&q=undelete+partition+usb+boot

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should buy a second HDD to store your data and than you should try to rescue your partition or make a new clean installation of both, Windows and Ubuntu.

If you can't afford a new HDD, accept that all your data is lost, in case the rescue won't work.

Try what was posted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121). You have to change the `/dev/hda` for your device.

EDIT: Never use Windows to resize your partitions. Always use some sort of Linux to do that, especially if you use a Dual-Boot! I always use gparted to resize my partitions if I have to.